# Attribute Value must be constant in @Retryable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this in my class and I calling them from `application.properties`

**Class A**

```
 @Value("${maxAttempts}")
    private String maxAttempt;
    @Value("${delay}")
    private String delay;
    @Value("${multiplier}")
    private String multiplier;
    @Value("${max-delay}")
    private String maxDelay;
```

And I use them in this line

```
 @Retryable(maxAttempts=maxAttempt, value=RuntimeException.class, backoff = @Backoff(delay =delay,multiplier = multiplier, maxDelay = maxDelay))
```

**application.properties**

```
maxAttempt=3
delay=3
max-delay=9
multiplier=2
```

However I get **Attribute Value must be constant**

---

**Edit**

```
@Value("${maxAttempts}")
    private int maxAttempt;
    @Value("${delay}")
    private int delay;
    @Value("${multiplier}")
    private int multiplier;
    @Value("${max-delay}")
    private int maxDelay;
```

---

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts="${maxAttempts}", value=RuntimeException.class, backoff = @Backoff(delay ="${delay}",multiplier = "${multiplier}", maxDelay = "${max-delay}"))//    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, value = RuntimeException.class, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000))
```

I get **found java lang string but required int**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staring from spring-retry-1.2.0 we can use configurable properties in @Retryable annotation.

Use "maxAttemptsExpression", Refer the below code for usage,

> @Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "#{${maxAttempts}}",  backoff =
>   @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{${delay}}"))

It will not work if you use any version less than 1.2.0.Also you don't require any configurable property classes.

Comment: Which version of Spring-retry are you using ?

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade to 1.2.0 ? As i mentioned in the answer it will not work if it is less than 1.2.0

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry Refer here for further reference ...

Comment: should i remove all this ? `@Value("${maxAttempts}") private String maxAttempt; @Value("${delay}") private String delay; @Value("${multiplier}") private String multiplier; @Value("${max-delay}") private String maxDelay;`

Comment: Yep you don't require this class  if you use 1.2.0.